# Replace the delimiter string in Json file

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have the json file with the delimiter values in it, I have to replace the delimeter($$....$$) with another delimiter value.

This is the input file

{
parameters:
{
"key" : "$$value$$"
}
}

Expected value is below.
{
parameters:
{
"key" : "$(value)"
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression,

```
"key"\s*:\s*"\$\$([^$]*)\$\$"
```

with a replacement of

```
"key":"$($1)"
```

might be an option.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GRpcWA/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/GRpcWA/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---